# Ionic 4 how to show more / less text?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to show text but in 2 lines but when user click on show more so he/she can see all text. This is my code

```
   <div *ngFor="let x of announcement">
         <ion-card class="group-box">
           <div text-left style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: white; top: 10%;position: relative; margin-left: 10px;">
             {{x.announcementTitle}}
           </div>
           <div class="" text-left style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: white; top: 25%;position: relative; margin-left: 10px;">
             {{x.announcementDetails}}
           </div>

           <div text-right class="announcement-username">
             {{x.createrName}}
           </div>
         </ion-card>
   </div>
```

I need to add option off seemore/less in annoucementDetails

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-show-more-less?embed=1&file=src/app/home/home.page.html)**

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let x of announcement">
    <ion-card class="group-box">
        <div>
            {{x.announcementTitle}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <div *ngIf="!x.showMore">
                {{trimString(x.announcementDetails,100)}}
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="x.showMore">
                {{x.announcementDetails}}
            </div>
            <a (click)="x.showMore = !x.showMore">Show <span [innerHtml]="x.showMore ? 'less' : 'More'">  </span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div text-right class="announcement-username">
            {{x.createrName}}
        </div>
    </ion-card>
</div>
```

.ts

```
 constructor() {
    this.announcement = this.announcement.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      showMore:false,
    }));
  }

  trimString(string, length) {
      return string.length > length ? 
             string.substring(0, length) + '...' :
             string;
  }
```

Comment: need your one more help when the description is small like one line its shtill showing see more option. How can i hide if text is less?

Comment: `<a (click)="x.showMore = !x.showMore" *ngIf="x.announcementDetails.length > 100">Show <span [innerHtml]="x.showMore ? 'less' : 'More'">  </span>
    </a>`

Comment: Add `*ngIf="x.announcementDetails.length> 100" `