# show more and show less in angular

Tags: angular, html-lists

How to do show more and show less in angular.If the list items(ordered list) is less than 2 show more should not visible and if list is more than 2 complete list should be visible and onclicking the show less it should show 2 listed items

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126898/ionic-4-how-to-show-more-less-text

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`.component.html`

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | slice:0:2">
    {{ item }}
  </li>
  <ng-container *ngIf="isExpanded">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let expandedItem of items; let i = index">
      <li *ngIf="i >= 2">
        {{ expandedItem }}
      </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <li *ngIf="items.length > 2 && !isExpanded">
    <button mat-button (click)="expandItems()">
      Show all
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`.component.ts`

```
expandItems() {
  this.expanded = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a playground for your case. you can play around

TS:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  values = [...Array(10).keys()];
  defaultLinkTitle = "showLess";
  onClick() {
    this.defaultLinkTitle =
      this.defaultLinkTitle === "showLess" ? "showMore" : "showLess";
    this.values =
      this.defaultLinkTitle === "showLess"
        ? this.values
        : this.values.slice(0, 2);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="datalist" *ngFor="let value of values">
  <li>value</li>
</ul>
<a *ngIf="values.length > 2" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="onClick()"
  >{{defaultLinkTitle}}</a
>
```

PlayGround : https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-dawn-best4